# Unity C# - Определение из какого скрипта удаляется игровой объект

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть ли возможность в Unity C# как-то определить из какого скрипта удаляется объект(Пролистывал все скрипты через поиск, так и не наткнулся на нужное место)

Comment: Используя встроенный Destroy нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Сделай экстеншн для GameObject который бы логировал бы эти данные или записывал куда-либо(как тебе удобнее).

Скажем, что-то вроде:

```
public static class DestroyLogger
{
    public static void DestroyLog(this GameObject go, MonoBehaviour monoObj)
    {
        Log(go.name + " destroyed from" + monoObj.GetType().Name)
        go.Destroy()
    }
}
```

соответственно, теперь ты можешь делать вот так:

```
someGo.DestroyLog(this);
```

код не проверялся. Если есть ошибки - исправишь сам. Главное - идея которую несет ответ)